# How can I read a Lucene document field tokens after they are analyzed?

Tags: lucene

If I create a document and add a field that is both stored and analyzed, how can I then read this field back as a list of tokens? I have the following:

```
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new Field("url", fileName, Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            doc.add(new Field("text", fileContent, Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED));
            // add the document to the index
            writer.addDocument(doc);
```

So the fileContext is a String containing a lot of text. It is analyzed whereby it is tokenized when it is stored in the index. However, how can I get these tokens? I can retrieve the document from the index after it is stored, and I can read the "text" field from the document, but this is returned as a string. I would like to get the tokens if possible. My 'writer' is an IndexWriter instance and it uses a StandardAnalyzer. Any pointers would be very much welcomed.

Thank you very much

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "tokens" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out `document.getField("name").tokenStreamValue()`.

EDIT: Actually [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638200/how-to-get-a-token-from-a-lucene-tokenstream) gives you the full solution using the above `TokenStream`.