# Fieldable.tokenStreamValue() returns null for tokenized field

Tags: lucene

I use lucene for N-Gram matching. I set a field to be analyzed using an N-Gram analyzer. I want to see how the tokens resulting from the analysis look like to make sure the n-grams are being correctly computed.

If I call the method `Fieldable.tokenStreamValue()` on the analyzed field of a document, I get null, while calling `Fieldable.isTokenized()` returns true.

I must add that the results of querying are consistent with n-grams being correctly generated.

Any explanations for this? I am essentially trying to do what is mentioned here:
[How can I read a Lucene document field tokens after they are analyzed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427845/how-can-i-read-a-lucene-document-field-tokens-after-they-are-analyzed)

Here is the full code:

```
public class TestLuceneNgram {

public static class NGramQuery extends BooleanQuery {

    public NGramQuery(final String queryTerm) throws IOException {

        StringReader strReader = new StringReader(queryTerm);
        TokenStream tokens = new NGramTokenizer(strReader);

        CharTermAttribute termAtt = (CharTermAttribute) tokens
                .addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

        while (tokens.incrementToken()) {
            System.out.println(termAtt);
            Term t = new Term("NGRAM_FIELD", termAtt.toString());
            add(new TermQuery(t), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

        }

    }
}

public static class NGramSearcher extends IndexSearcher {

    public NGramSearcher(final Directory directory)
            throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {
        super(IndexReader.open(directory));
    }

    public TopDocs search(final String term) {
        try {
            return search(new NGramQuery(term), 10);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public static class SubWordAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

    @Override
    public TokenStream tokenStream(final String fieldName,
            final Reader reader) {
        return new NGramTokenizer(reader);
    }

}

public static Directory index(final String[] terms) {

    Directory indexDirectory = new RAMDirectory();

    IndexWriter indexWriter = null;
    try {
        indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory,
                new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_32,
                        new SubWordAnalyzer()));
    } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LockObtainFailedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; ++i) {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new Field("NGRAM_FIELD", terms[i], Field.Store.YES,
                Field.Index.ANALYZED,
                Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
        doc.add(new Field("ORIGINAL_FIELD", terms[i], Field.Store.YES,
                Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

        try {
            indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
        } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        indexWriter.optimize();
    } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        indexWriter.close();
    } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return indexDirectory;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    String[] terms = new String[] { "the first string", "the second one" };

    Directory dir = index(terms);

    NGramSearcher ngs = null;
    try {
        ngs = new NGramSearcher(dir);
    } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    TopDocs td = ngs.search("second");
    System.out.println(td.totalHits);

    for (ScoreDoc sd : td.scoreDocs) {
        System.out.println(sd.doc + "---" + sd.score);
        try {
            System.out.println(ngs.doc(sd.doc).getFieldable("NGRAM_FIELD").
            tokenStreamValue());

        } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638200/how-to-get-a-token-from-a-lucene-tokenstream/2638252#2638252 ?

Comment: The issue is that the `TokenStream` object is null, so I cannot proceed until I know why this is the case.

Comment: This is how I obtain a tokenstream from the indexReader: `TokenStream ts = TokenSources.getTokenStream(indexReader, luceneDocId, luceneFieldName);` I never used Fieldable.tokenStreamValue() and also, without you submitting your code, it is hard to find out what goes wrong.

Comment: Have you tried looking at it with Luke?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is whether you are actually storing this field at index time. If you're just indexing it, this is the expected result.