# Hibernate full text search matching

Tags: spring, hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I have two users with name 'Alex' and 'Andrei'. When i write query like 'A', I get 0 results.  I have to search with the full name and matching capitalization to get a result.

I want for example just query for 'e' end receive 2 records.

```
    Session s = session.getCurrentSession();

    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(s);

    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(User.class).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query q = qb
            .keyword().onFields("name")
            .matching(query)
            .createQuery();

    org.hibernate.Query hibQuery =
            fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(q, User.class);

    List<User> results = hibQuery.list();
```

Comment: Analysis sounds like your issue.  You should read up on that: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e392 .   Don't really understand why a query for "e" would find "Alex".  Maybe look into ngram analysis, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing how you index the first names. This is as well important. For example if you store index them un-analyzed, you need to take indeed capitalization into account. Also as mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468881/hibernate-full-text-search-matching#comment47112413_29468881), you need to look at the right analyzer. You case would only work if you were to use wildcard queries.

On a tangent, I don't know how close your example is to your actual usecase, but searching for a single character is probably not a typical free-text search use-case.

Answer (score 0):

This particular behavior reminds me one error I got once.

'A' is a stop word (in English language) used by the standard analyzer of Hibernate Search, so you have to precise a custom analyser without this stop word.

**These Links could help you**

To use a custom analyzer: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.1/reference/en/html/search-mapping.html

To understand what I mean with 'a' like a stop word: [Getting error on a specific query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765698/getting-error-on-a-specific-query)