# How do I "Delimit" a buffered reader with a text document?

Tags: java, text, delimiter, punctuation, buffered

So, I am trying to read in a document (.txt) into a java project using a buffered reader, edit it, and return it/output it. The issue I'm having is that I can't get the punctuation to be recognized.
The document reads:

hello hello.hello,hello/hello?

As a test of the different circumstances I want to be able to handle.
And I get:

hello hello hello hello hello

Any suggestions?
(will provide sections of code if needed for answer)
I was thinking about using a delimiter but can't figure out how that would be contextually (or if it is even possible with a buffered reader).

BTW, I am reading and editing this document character by character and running it through checks in multiple arrays for including certain characters. If that helps.

Comment: So if `hello hello.hello,hello/hello?` is your input, what is the expected output? I'm a little confused by your wording.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole file into a String by looping [readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) (not recommended for large files)

Then on the string:

```
String.split("[\s.,/]")
```

This will split your string on several different characters.

Or if you want to split on all non-letters:

```
String.split("[^A-Za-z]")
```

This will give you an array of strings, which is rather easy to work with. Then you just write back at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle all the punctuation marks and whitespaces, I'd suggest you go for lucene tokenizer and get the work done.
A sample implementation is given here
[How to use a Lucene Analyzer to tokenize a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334692/how-to-use-a-lucene-analyzer-to-tokenize-a-string)
But this depends on what your requirements are. If it is just commas and whitespaces, then a regex would do the needful