# How Do I Use BrazilianStemmer in Lucene 4?

Tags: java, lucene, nlp, information-retrieval, stemming

i'm trying to tokenize and stem a portuguese sentence using Lucene 4.

Based on this [thread] ([How to use a Lucene Analyzer to tokenize a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334692/how-to-use-a-lucene-analyzer-to-tokenize-a-string)) i was abble to correctly tokenize a portuguese sentence. However, no stemming were been applied. Thus, reading the Lucene 4 documentation, i found this class [BrazilianStemmer] (https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/br/BrazilianStemmer.html).

I alter my code to use this BrazilianStemmer class.

```
    public static StringBuffer tokenizeString(StringBuffer text) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    try {

        Analyzer analyzer = new PortugueseAnalyzer();

        TokenStream stream  = analyzer.tokenStream(null, new StringReader(text.toString()));
        stream.reset();

        BrazilianStemFilter filter = new BrazilianStemFilter(stream);

        while (filter.incrementToken()) {
            result.append(filter.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class).toString());
            result.append(" ");
        }

        filter.close();
        analyzer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But, I'm not sure that it is working properly. Is this the right and better way to achieve a stemming from Lucene for foreign languages?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the right way to do that you are applying a stemmer twice, because the PortugueseAnalyzer use internally a PortugueseLightStemFilter as you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/trunk/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pt/PortugueseAnalyzer.java#L123).

Is better if you create your custom analyzer like this:

```
    Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
       @Override
        protected Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
            final Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(reader);
            TokenStream result = new LowerCaseFilter(source);
            result = new StopFilter(result, PortugueseAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet());
            result = new BrazilianStemFilter(result);
            return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);
        }
    };
```