# How to test a Lucene Analyzer?

Tags: java, lucene, token, tokenize, analyzer

I'm not getting the expected results from my `Analyzer` and would like to test the tokenization process.

The answer this question: [How to use a Lucene Analyzer to tokenize a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334692/how-to-use-a-lucene-analyzer-to-tokenize-a-string)

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
TokenStream stream  = analyzer.tokenStream(field, new StringReader(keywords));

try {
    while(stream.incrementToken()) {
        result.add(stream.getAttribute(TermAttribute.class).term());
    }
}
catch(IOException e) {
    // not thrown b/c we're using a string reader...
}

return result;
```

Uses the `TermAttribute` to extract the tokens from the stream. The problem is that `TermAttribute` is no longer in Lucene 6.

What has it been replaced by?

What would the equivalent be with Lucene 6.6.0?

Comment: As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2638252/981744) describes, TermAttribute was replaced with `CharTermAttribute`. I'm not a Lucene expert but this is what you get a from a little Googling.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBolwidt, that answer was exactly what I was looking for... my lucene vocabulary is clearly lacking. Can you you throw it in answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it was replaced by `CharTermAttribute` [javadoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/tokenattributes/CharTermAttribute.html)

The ticket is pretty old, but maybe the code was kept around a bit longer:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2372